# Keyboard Shortcut to go full screen in Webstorm/IntelliJ Terminal tool window from terminal?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, webstorm

I googled but have not found any solving documentation/thread regarding this:

Is there a way to set keyboard shortcut to go full screen in Webstorm Terminal tool window from Terminal window?

I know shortcut shift+Command+' but that doesn't work for me inside terminal. I know by double clicking it you can toggle it to full screen but wondering that is it possible to set keyboard shortcut to do it as I do this operation often.

Comment: Terminal is a special place: on one hand people want to have their IDE shortcuts working as is there as well; on another hand -- nope, that shortcut must go into terminal to my console app/script (the best example I think would be `Esc` key -- "I want my script to accept Esc .. and at the same time I still want Esc to do default job -- move focus back to editor"). Therefore the best option would be finding some shortcut and assigning it to a Full Screen mode that would work fine from Terminal (e.g. something with F1-F12 keys in it, *I guess*)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try the "Maximize tool window" command in the menu - `Window`->`Active Tool Window`->`Maximize tool window`

[image: from main toolbar menu]

Or from terminal tool menu - `Resize`-> `Maximize tool window`

[image: from terminal tool menu]

> **Warning!** The following shortcut only works if "Override IDE shortcuts" option is disabled

To map a shortcut to this, open the Preferences dialog and type "Maximize tool window" to search the settings. It should find a match in the keymap section, and you can then use it to assign a shortcut.

[image: image-of-webstorm-maximize-tool-window-setting]

It will warn you if you already have something assigned to your choice.

> **Warning!** The following option will cause some problems in Terminal, for example, editing in vim (`Esc` key) etc.

Also, you can to checkout the "Override IDE shortcuts" setting in the Terminal section of the Preferences. This is enabled by default - I turn it off and find it resolves a lot of niggles I have with using the terminal. The shortcut above only works if it's disabled.

[image: checkout Override IDE shortcuts]

Comment: great answer! in PhpStorm 2016.2.1 the default shortcut is `Ctrl + Shift + "` (on Win/Linux), but it works only after disabling IDE shortcuts in `Terminal` settings, as shown above.

Comment: Didn't know about this setting! Tried many shortcut assignments but mysteriously failed.

Comment: Ctrl+shift+" doesn't seem to work anymore, nothing happens, (Community edition 2020.3.2 on Ubuntu 20.04.)

Answer (score 13):

In Mac cmd+shift+fn+12 will do the trick

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: ctrl+shift+f12 windows. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I mostly like zen mode - cmd(ctrl)+K,Z

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMkNI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Double press 'escape' from anywhere will bring you back to editor tab.